# How to calculate the distance to the nearest higher value in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, kdb, dolphindb

In my dataset, there's a column named “f1“. Given a specific row with a value of 10, I want to find the nearest higher value **above** it, which is 11 in the first row. The distance between them is 4 (rows). I intend to store this value in a new column called “f2”.

Similarly, I want to find the nearest higher value **below** this row, which is 12 in the last row. The distance between them is 2 (rows). I intend to record this value in a new column named "f3".

[image]

Below is the KDB+ script for the calculation:

[image]

Could you please assist me in converting this script into DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1:

```
f1 = 11 8 9 9 10 9 12
// Calculate the distance: the index of all elements greater than the current element - the index of the current element
fx = eachRight(drop, isort f1, 1+rank f1) - til count f1
def findPrev(x): max iif(x<0, x, 00i) // Find the maximum negative distance (closest element before the current element)
def findNext(x): min iif(x>0, x, 00i) // Find the minimum positive distance (closest element after the current element)
table(f1, each(findPrev, fx) as f2, each(findNext, fx) as f3)
```

Method 2:

If dealing with a large vector, this method will offer better performance.

```
f1 = 11 8 9 9 10 9 12
def dist(x, i) : ifirstHit(>, x.subarray(i:x.size()), x[i-1]) + 1
table(f1, each(dist{f1.reverse()}, size(f1)..1).replace!(0, 00i) as f2, each(dist{f1}, 1..size(f1)).replace!(0, 00i) as f3)
```